# CRUD GUI from jsp page, on rest maven project

Tags: javascript, java, rest, maven, jsp

I am struggling with a GUI for a maven project. The whole thing is working perfectly I know through JUnit testing. I have tried various things which I will now show although I know its not the best way of doing it. There has to be some sort of easier way to do this.

OK..so I have connected to database, I can return all the info to a JSP page in either a string or an object, neither are ideal as the object will return with [] brackets either side of the list and the string is just not ideal as i'd like maybe to use delete and update buttons beside each entry.

string and object retrieval at the minute

index.jsp

```
<p><a href="webapi/cds">All Entries</a></p>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>Assignment.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

new.jsp

```
<b><%= request.getParameter("test") %></b>

<b><%= request.getAttribute("test1") %></b>
```

CD Resource

```
@GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
    public Response getAllCDs()
    {
        List<CD> list = cdRepos.findAllCD();

        String sentence="";

        for (CD c: list)
        {
            sentence+="ID : "+c.getId()+"<br>Artist : "+c.getArtistName()+"<br>Title : "+c.getTitle()+"<br>Duration : "+c.getDuration()+"<hr>";
        }

        URI uri = UriBuilder.fromPath("/rest/new.jsp")
                .queryParam("test", list)
                .build();
        return Response.seeOther(uri).build();



//      return list; //this returns the cd list in json
//      java.net.URI location = null;
//      try {
//          location = new java.net.URI("http://localhost:8080/rest/new.jsp");
//      } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
//          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//          e.printStackTrace();
//      }
//      CD cdt = new CD();
//      cdt.setArtistName("hello World");
//      return  Response.temporaryRedirect(location).entity(cdt).build();
    }
```

CDClient.java

```
public CD get(String id)
{
    System.out.println("ye getting to here");
    WebTarget target =  client.target("http://localhost:8080/rest/webapi/");

    Response response = target.path("cds/"+id).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(Response.class);


    if(response.getStatus() != 200)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(response.getStatus()+ " there was an error on the server");
    }
    return response.readEntity(CD.class);
}

public List<CD> get()
{
    WebTarget target =  client.target("http://localhost:8080/rest/webapi/");
    List<CD> response = target.path("cds").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(new GenericType<List<CD>>(){});



    return response;
}
```

Please and Thanks

Comment: I'm confused, could you be clear of what do you want, please?

Comment: Im looking for some help on a better way to do this, what is the best way to make a jsp page gui for the CRUD program i have made

Comment: I think REST rocks, you could make endpoints for any action, using the right http methods, and access it via Ajax calls, using Jquery or something like that.